# Why is this Ajax Code Igniter call not working?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am a bit confused as to why this CI Ajax call is not working? I receive a response if I set $SearchTerm to be a string, but it does not receive the "search" POST from AJAX? Is there a setting in Code Igniter that I need to change? THANKS!

```
jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'home/getAjaxData/',
      data: 'search=1',
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(resp) {
         Alert (resp);
      }
  });

 public function getAjaxData() {
    $SearchTerm = $this->input->post('search');
    echo $SearchTerm;       
 }
```

Comment: Change `GET` to `POST`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
 $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo site_url('home/getAjaxData'); ?>",
          data: {search:'1'},
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(resp) {
             Alert (resp);
          }
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code $this->input->post('search'), I think it only works with post in CodeIgniter. You can get value of textbox by using jQuery, example:

```
<input type="textbox" name="text" /><br/>
$('input[name="text"]').val();
```

And in your controller, as @badbetonbreakbutbedbac said, you can get search value by:

```
$search= (int)$_REQUEST['search'];
echo $search;
```

Answer (score 0):

If ajax GET calls works fine with CI, but ajax POST not work - check CSRF protection. Disable it for test (application/config/config.php):

```
$config['csrf_protection']  = FALSE;
```

And if then ajax POST calls start working, you can enable protection again and add ci_csrf_token as part as ajax data.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `POST` instead of `GET`

```
 jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'home/getAjaxData/',
      data: 'search=1',
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(resp) {
         alert(resp);
      }
  });
```

Since you are sending your data through POST this is function will work properly

```
public function getAjaxData() {
    $SearchTerm = $this->input->post('search');
    echo $SearchTerm;       
 }
```